# Stop Advanced Forum cutting off the username?

Tags: nodes

Im using the Advanced Forum module. Many of my users have long usernames which are being cut off (in the author information when they post a comment). Is it possible to lengten the limit before the text is cut off?

I cant see any settings for the Forum or Advanced Forum modules. Below is a theme hook that creates the author information (dont know if this is the right track or not).

```
/**
 * Theme function to show simple author pane when not using Author Pane.
 */
function theme_advanced_forum_simple_author_pane(&$variables) {
  $context = $variables['context'];
  // Sending the context rather than the account makes it work for anon comments.
  $name = theme('username', array('account' => $context));

  $account = user_load($context->uid);
  $picture = theme('user_picture', array('account' => $account));

  return '<div class="author-pane">' . $name . $picture . '</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Drupal core truncates the username to 25 characters. I have not tried this but [this seems to be the solution](http://drupal.org/node/854762#comment-6737992) for Drupal 7 (code added below for reference).

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_username(&$vars) {

  // Update the username so it's the full name of the user.
  $account = $vars['account'];

  // Revise the name trimming done in template_preprocess_username.
  $name = $vars['name_raw'] = format_username($account);

  // Trim the altered name as core does, but with a higher character limit.
  if (drupal_strlen($name) > 25) {
    $name = drupal_substr($name, 0, 20) . '...';
  }

  // Assign the altered name to $vars['name'].
  $vars['name'] = check_plain($name);

}
```

Add this code in your theme's template.php file, and change MYTHEME to the machine name of your theme, and change the number `25` to something that fits your theme.

Answer (score 1):

The code that truncates the username is in [template_preprocess_username()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_username/7). If you want to get a longer username, you can implement the following code in your theme, or your module.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  if (drupal_strlen($variables['name_raw']) > MYMODULE_MAXIMUM_USERNAME_LENGTH) {
    $name = drupal_substr($variables['name_raw'], 0, MYMODULE_MAXIMUM_USERNAME_LENGTH - 5) . '...';
    $variables['name'] = check_plain($name);
  }
}
```

`template_preprocess_username()` is executed before `mymodule_preprocess_username()` (or `mytheme_preprocess_username()`), which is then executed before [theme_username()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_username/7).

As `template_preprocess_username()` sets `$variables['name_raw']` to the raw username, all your module/theme needs to do is to set `$variables['name']` truncating `$variables['name_raw']` to the length you want. (Replace `MYMODULE_MAXIMUM_USERNAME_LENGTH` with the desired length.)

```
  // This is the code executed from template_preprocess_username().

  // Set the name to a formatted name that is safe for printing and
  // that won't break tables by being too long. Keep an unshortened,
  // unsanitized version, in case other preprocess functions want to implement
  // their own shortening logic or add markup. If they do so, they must ensure
  // that $variables['name'] is safe for printing.
  $name = $variables['name_raw'] = format_username($account);
  if (drupal_strlen($name) > 20) {
    $name = drupal_substr($name, 0, 15) . '...';
  }
  $variables['name'] = check_plain($name);
```

If you don't want to truncate the username, you can use the following code, in a module, or a theme.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
  $variables['name'] = check_plain($variables['name_raw']);
}
```